# How to access all local storage from all sites visited?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When developing in Visual Studio, html pages can be run in a temporary localhost, e.g. http://localhost:64371. Different each time VS is run.
How can I access the local storage items saved from previous runs? I don't know what ports were used. Is there a way to view all local storage from all sites? A browser like Chrome, F12, Application, Local Storage only shows the current site.

Comment: Do you know if they even still exist?  Their being referred to as "temporary" raises some doubt...

Comment: Use cookie storage instead of local storage

Comment: ... or a better development setup.

Comment: Why not set up your config so it uses the same port each time?

Comment: I just tried this on Chrome and Edge and under the F12 Application tab it lists localStorage for all sites that use it.  Yet, if you've configured your browser to clear storage on exit then that would be a problem.

Comment: So the consensus is, it is not possible to access local storage except from the site one is on at the time, and data stored by a previous site can not be retrieved, even if it still exists. ?